# Sending list of string (xml or json) from windowsphone to mvc4 webapi

Tags: windows-phone-7, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am new to windows-phone as well as  mvc4 Web-API. I am trying to Send details from windows-phone and want to get those details in mvc4 web-API as an Query string. I have the list of data now but i don't know how to send it and receive it in Web-API need suggestion or sample links.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking into this [Contact Manager Web API sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Contact-Manager-Web-API-0e8e373d.).

> I am trying to Send details from windows-phone and want to get those details in mvc4 web-API as an Query string

**Solution #1:**
By passing the list of string from query string, you will need to mark your action parameter as [FromUri] ...

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromUri] List<string> arrOfString)
    {
    }
}
```

... and the query string will need to be in the form of arrOfString[]=item1&arrayOfString[]=item2&...&arrayOfString[]=itemN.  Here is an example of what your Windows Phone might look like:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(...);
        client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/api/values?arrOfString[]=a&arrayOfString[]=b&arrayOfString[]=c"), string.Empty);
```

**Solution #2:**
Alternatively, you can don't have hard requirements to pass in data in the query string, it's simplier to pass the list of string in the request body:

Web API Server:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/values
    public void Post(List<string> arrOfString)
    {
    }
}
```

Windows Phone Client:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });

        client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(...);
        client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/api/values"), "POST", data);
```

Comment: I have been trying that example for sometime. For me the problem is that example helps me to know how to fetch detail from web-API to phone.. i Want something like phone to Web-API. In that example its tough for me to follow the phone to web-API. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I have updated the answer with some sample code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Checking out Your answers. I will Work it out. It looks good thank You